expected value of type "_Any" in apollo federation
{
  "representations": [
    {
      "__typename": "dummy",
      "templateId": "X",
      "strategy": "dummy",
      "listingVariant": {
        "__typename": "dummy",
        "internalSku": "dummy",
        "market": "{\"brandCatalogId\":X,\"storeId\":X,\"brand\":null,\"channel\":null,\"country\":null,\"locale\":\"en_US\",\"location\":null,\"segment\":null}",
        "selections": [],
        "listing": {
          "__typename": "Dummy",
          "primaryClass": {
            "classId": X
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "subStrategyId": "Dummy",
  "preferredShipToLocation": {
    "postalCode": "XXXXX"
  },
  "count": X
}

this is the variables i put for my query when i try to run graphiql locally. but i get an error saying - 'expected value of type "_Any"'. I am not sure why that's happening cuz it seems like i am providing the correct json obj for `representations`
expect the error to go away

From taking a glance at the docs you might want to ensure the root query returning _entities is being properly resolved in each subgraph
It has params of type [_Any!]!
Docs

